# Bootstrap 4 nested tabs not removing active

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have some nested tabs, vertical and horizontal but they don't switch the active states or it gets buggy

```css
body
{
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid row c2" id="my_jiku_box">
<div class="col-12 row" id="args">
  <div class="col-4 nav flex-column nav-pills c1" id="vertMenu" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#v-pills-0" data-toggle="pill" role="tab"
    aria-controls="#v-pills-0" aria-expanded="true">1980 Markina attack<span class=
    "spaceTimeInfo">Spain, 20 September 1980</span></a><a class="nav-link" href=
    "#v-pills-1" data-toggle="pill" role="tab" aria-controls="#v-pills-1"
    aria-expanded="false">Cafeter&iacute;a Rolando bombing<span class=
    "spaceTimeInfo">Spain, 13 September 1974</span></a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-8" id="horMenu">
    <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade active show" aria-labelledby="v-pills-0" id=
      "v-pills-0">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" role="tablist" id="pills-tab0">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#pills-0"
          data-toggle="pill" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-0" aria-expanded=
          "true">Text</a></li>

          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#pills-images0" data-toggle=
          "pill" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-0" aria-expanded=
          "true">Images</a></li>

          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#pills-videos0" data-toggle=
          "pill" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-0">Videos</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="pills-0">
            <div class="toolbar">
              <a data-command="bold" href="#"></a><a data-command="italic" href=
              "#"></a><a data-command="underline" href="#"></a><a data-command=
              "strikeThrough" href="#"></a>
            </div>

            <div class="dropEL col">
              <div class="drag-header">
                Drag and resize me!
              </div>

              <p class="content_jiku" contenteditable="true">The 1980 Markina attack
              was a gun attack by the Basque separatist organisation ETA which
              occurred on 20 September 1980 near the Basque town of Markina (Spanish:
              ). The targets were a group of off-duty civil guards who were having
              lunch in a bar in the town. Four civil guards were killed. The attack
              was one of the deadliest of 1980, the year when ETA killed more people
              than any other.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="tab-pane fade dropEL col" id="pills-images0">
          <div class="drag-header"></div><img class="img-fluid" src=
          "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/z9R-exzTZRIbnzTVezVAK9u4GLKmJxavscBKYnJnZqb25oDK2aF0pbC3K1BppdKBabOaxUMTB6L8_A1bTxp_0V_zqwmV2z4_MBJH0_67azUnVp02JeQThcFNVfOj8K_hN4OYKAdXPjGWjgfE8jY=-rj-w300-h300-l95-c0x039be5" /></div>

          <div class="tab-pane fade dropEL col" id="pills-videos0">
            <div class="drag-header"></div>

            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
              <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src=
              "https://www.youtube.com/embed/vQMSwhfnwZI?rel=0&amp;modestbranding=1"></iframe>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tab-pane fade" aria-labelledby="v-pills-1" id="v-pills-1">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" role="tablist" id="pills-tab1">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#pills-1" data-toggle="pill"
          role="tab" aria-controls="pills-1" aria-expanded="false">Text</a></li>

          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#pills-images1" data-toggle=
          "pill" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-1" aria-expanded=
          "false">Images</a></li>

          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#pills-videos1" data-toggle=
          "pill" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-1">Videos</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-1">
            <div class="toolbar">
              <a data-command="bold" href="#"></a><a data-command="italic" href=
              "#"></a><a data-command="underline" href="#"></a><a data-command=
              "strikeThrough" href="#"></a>
            </div>

            <div class="dropEL col">
              <div class="drag-header">
                Drag and resize me!
              </div>

              <p class="content_jiku" contenteditable="true">The Cafeter&iacute;a
              Rolando bombing was an attack on 13 September 1974 at the Rolando cafe
              in Calle del Correo, Madrid, Spain which killed 13 people and wounded
              71. Though no claim of responsibility was made, the attack is widely
              believed to have been carried out by the armed Basque separatist group
              ETA.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="tab-pane fade dropEL col" id="pills-images1">
          <div class="drag-header"></div><img class="img-fluid" src=
          "https://i2.wp.com/upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/67/Real_Casa_de_Correos_%28Madrid%29_05b.jpg/1280px-Real_Casa_de_Correos_%28Madrid%29_05b.jpg" /></div>

          <div class="tab-pane fade dropEL col" id="pills-videos1">
            <div class="drag-header"></div>

            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
              <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src=
              "https://www.youtube.com/embed/VVOCg3kInUk?rel=0&amp;modestbranding=1"></iframe>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-6 row col"></div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ma0yt7k/27/) here, I am basically trying to mix a [bootstrap vertical tab](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#tabs) menu which switches a horizontal tab system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a dummy class mainTab to tabs on the left side to identify vertical tabs from horizontal tabs. Add this code to your click function after declaration of panel variable. I have pasted the code which is working for me inside an external html file, and also the fiddle if i make the viewport size bigger. Only thing is that there are some console errors which are un-related to this issue. "Failed to construct 'PresentationRequest': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-presentation' flag".

Another thing that you may have to set is default horizontal tag active on load.

Your nested tabs were not removing active color because of nav-pills class on outer div.

```
 <div class="container-fluid row c2" id="my_jiku_box">
    <div class="col-6 row" id="args">
      <div class="col-4 nav flex-column nav-pills c1" id="vertMenu" role="tablist">
        <a class="nav-link active mainTab" href="#v-pills-0" data-toggle="pill" role="tab"
        aria-controls="#v-pills-0" aria-expanded="true">1980 Markina attack<span class=
        "spaceTimeInfo">Spain, 20 September 1980</span></a><a class="nav-link mainTab" href=
        "#v-pills-1" data-toggle="pill" role="tab" aria-controls="#v-pills-1"
        aria-expanded="false">Cafeter&iacute;a Rolando bombing<span class=
        "spaceTimeInfo">Spain, 13 September 1974</span></a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-8" id="horMenu">
        <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
          <div class="tab-pane fade active show hMain" aria-labelledby="v-pills-0" id=
          "v-pills-0">
            <ul class="nav nav-justified" role="tablist" id="pills-tab0">
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#pills-0"
              data-toggle="pill" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-0" aria-expanded=
              "true">Text</a></li>

              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#pills-images0" data-toggle=
              "pill" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-0" aria-expanded=
              "true">Images</a></li>

              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#pills-videos0" data-toggle=
              "pill" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-0">Videos</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
              <div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="pills-0">
                <div class="toolbar">
                  <a data-command="bold" href="#"></a><a data-command="italic" href=
                  "#"></a><a data-command="underline" href="#"></a><a data-command=
                  "strikeThrough" href="#"></a>
                </div>

                <div class="dropEL col">
                  <div class="drag-header">
                    Drag and resize me!
                  </div>

                  <p class="content_jiku" contenteditable="true">The 1980 Markina attack
                  was a gun attack by the Basque separatist organisation ETA which
                  occurred on 20 September 1980 near the Basque town of Markina (Spanish:
                  ). The targets were a group of off-duty civil guards who were having
                  lunch in a bar in the town. Four civil guards were killed. The attack
                  was one of the deadliest of 1980, the year when ETA killed more people
                  than any other.</p>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="tab-pane fade dropEL col" id="pills-images0">
              <div class="drag-header"></div><img class="img-fluid" src=
              "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/z9R-exzTZRIbnzTVezVAK9u4GLKmJxavscBKYnJnZqb25oDK2aF0pbC3K1BppdKBabOaxUMTB6L8_A1bTxp_0V_zqwmV2z4_MBJH0_67azUnVp02JeQThcFNVfOj8K_hN4OYKAdXPjGWjgfE8jY=-rj-w300-h300-l95-c0x039be5" /></div>

              <div class="tab-pane fade dropEL col" id="pills-videos0">
                <div class="drag-header"></div>

                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src=
                  "https://www.youtube.com/embed/vQMSwhfnwZI?rel=0&amp;modestbranding=1"></iframe>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="tab-pane fade hMain" aria-labelledby="v-pills-1" id="v-pills-1">
            <ul class="nav nav-justified" role="tablist" id="pills-tab1">
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#pills-1" data-toggle="pill"
              role="tab" aria-controls="pills-1" aria-expanded="false">Text</a></li>

              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#pills-images1" data-toggle=
              "pill" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-1" aria-expanded=
              "false">Images</a></li>

              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#pills-videos1" data-toggle=
              "pill" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-1">Videos</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
              <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-1">
                <div class="toolbar">
                  <a data-command="bold" href="#"></a><a data-command="italic" href=
                  "#"></a><a data-command="underline" href="#"></a><a data-command=
                  "strikeThrough" href="#"></a>
                </div>

                <div class="dropEL col">
                  <div class="drag-header">
                    Drag and resize me!
                  </div>

                  <p class="content_jiku" contenteditable="true">The Cafeter&iacute;a
                  Rolando bombing was an attack on 13 September 1974 at the Rolando cafe
                  in Calle del Correo, Madrid, Spain which killed 13 people and wounded
                  71. Though no claim of responsibility was made, the attack is widely
                  believed to have been carried out by the armed Basque separatist group
                  ETA.</p>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="tab-pane fade dropEL col" id="pills-images1">
              <div class="drag-header"></div><img class="img-fluid" src=
              "https://i2.wp.com/upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/67/Real_Casa_de_Correos_%28Madrid%29_05b.jpg/1280px-Real_Casa_de_Correos_%28Madrid%29_05b.jpg" /></div>

              <div class="tab-pane fade dropEL col" id="pills-videos1">
                <div class="drag-header"></div>

                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src=
                  "https://www.youtube.com/embed/VVOCg3kInUk?rel=0&amp;modestbranding=1"></iframe>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-6 row col"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".nav-link").removeClass("active");
  var elem = $(".mainTab")[0];

  $(elem).addClass("active");
  var href=$(elem).attr("href")
  console.log(href);
  $("div"+href).show();
  console.log($("div"+href).find(".nav-link")[0]);
  $($("div"+href).find(".nav-link")[0]).addClass("nav-pills");
});
           $(".nav-link").click(function(){
          var me = $(this);
          var panel = $('#' + this.hash.substr(1).toLowerCase());

          if(me.hasClass("mainTab"))
          {
            $(".nav-link.active").removeClass("active");

            var href=me.attr("href");
            $("div.hMain").hide();   
            $("div.hMain").removeClass("active");
            $("div"+href).show();
          }
          me.parent().addClass('nav-pills');
          if(me.hasClass('active')){
             $(".nav-link.active").removeClass("active");
             me.removeClass('active');

             panel.removeClass('active');     
                return false;
          }
        });
   </script>
```

Comment: it is still buggy, unless I have done a mistake https://jsfiddle.net/3ma0yt7k/30/

Comment: still not working, try to go here with your code, https://jsfiddle.net/3ma0yt7k/33/, then try to click on the tabs, it will show you both tabs at some point

Comment: you copy pasted it incorrectly in the fiddle. forgot the line $(document).ready(function(){

Comment: no man, try to click on the left vertical menu, one button, then anther button, then again the other button and you will see that both horizontal menus appear even with document ready https://jsfiddle.net/3ma0yt7k/34/

Comment: In your fiddle, you have one extra set of closing braces }); in the last line of javascript part. Remove that and run the fiddle. It works for me.

Comment: i have made also my own answer with a simpler js logic, will add this answer too on this question https://jsfiddle.net/3ma0yt7k/53/

Comment: sure...that will be good for people who reference it in future.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the `html` in the question, I re-created the logic by adding and removing the class `active` based on the `id` if this matches the `href` of the clicked `element`

```
$(".col-4 .nav-link").on("click", function(){
  var curId = $(this).attr("href");
  $(".tab-pane").removeClass("active show");
  $(".nav-justified .nav-link").removeClass("active");
  $(".tab-pane" + curId).addClass("active show");
});
```

[jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/3ma0yt7k/55/)